# Assigning boolean to a value through tinker in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to create a user through tinker and assign the value of 1 to a boolean field that defaults to 0.
But it always saves the default value of 0 instead of setting the value to 1.

Here is what I've tried(all the other fields get the proper value):

```
App\User::create(['email' => 'mail@mail.net','password' => 
bcrypt('password'),'is_admin' => 1])

... 'is_admin' => '1'

... 'is_admin' => true

... 'is_admin' => 'true'
```

Here is my migration:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->boolean('is_admin')->default(false);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
App\User::create(['email' => 'mail@mail.net','password' =>bcrypt('password'),
                  'is_admin' => boolval(1)]);
```

and verify if `is_admin` is `$fillable` in your model;

```
protected $fillable = ['email','password','is_admin'];
```

Only fillable attributes are available for [Mass Assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#mass-assignment)